# Dataframe df has blank col. 'Key' & col. 'News'. A list has keywords & 1 or more appear in "News' and keywords should be filled in col. 'key' in df

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, contains

sample data
df dataframe

```
Key         News
            Tata Steel results   
            Oracle results and announce buyback
            Bhart Airtel  results, dividend:
```

The keyword List is `{'result', 'buyback', 'dividend'}`

The dataframe `df` is already filtered from a larger data frame by me based on list and contains at least one keyword from the list in the 'News" column.
The command used was

```
df = df_large[df_large['News'].str.contains('|'.join(list)]
```

Desired Result:
want  'key' in df to be populated by keyword (one or more) in the List, depending on how many of them appear in the "News' column in  df.
df should look like.

```
Key                 NEWS 
result              Tata Steel results    
dividend            Oracle results and announce buyback
result, buyback     Bhart Airtel results, dividend
```

Is iteration the only way. even if yes, what is the optimum way.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set up our data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['News'], data = ['Tata Steel results', 'Oracle results and announce buyback', 'Bhart Airtel  results, dividend:'])
keywords = ['result', 'buyback', 'dividend']
```

Now we define the function that filters the full keyword list to those that are in `text`:

```
def filter_key_list(text, keys = keywords):
    return ','.join([k for k in keys if k in text])
```

Now we can `map` this to the `News` column:

```
df['Keys'] = df['News'].map(filter_key_list)
df
```

output:

```
    News                                Keys
0   Tata Steel results                  result
1   Oracle results and announce buyback result,buyback
2   Bhart Airtel results, dividend:     result,dividend
```

Comment: Thanks that worked nicely. I am more familiar with old programming techniques and  was doing it through a for loop. It will be helpful if you can explain this is better than that approach resources wise.

Comment: resource wise is the same. `map` does a for loop behind the scenes. But it looks nicer! If you are happy with the answer consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am happy with the answer and will do the needful by accepting it. One last thing. If I have a additional column say  "Details" in df  which also I want to checkup for  same keywords like the column  'News',  should i do it separately or there can be one command.  If the keyword is appearing  either or in both  columns 'News" and 'Details' it should appear only once in column "key' in df.

Comment: I would do `(df['News'] + df['Details']).map(filter_key_list)` where `+` would concatenate the text in the two columns, so we would be checking for keywords in the news and the details